# Using collapsible elements like an accordian - Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen with Bootstrap 3 the default functionality for accordians is to close other collapsible elements when one is open.

Is it possible to do this just using collapse?

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapse5">

    <p> venenatis tincidunt. Fusce at dolor nunc. 
        Duis maximus pulvinar leo, id laoreet massa tincidunt ut. 
        Quisque scelerisque sit amet ipsum eget ornare. 
        Donec eu blandit lectus. Suspendisse potenti. 
        Praesent posuere enim sapien. Etiam et ullamcorper sem. 
        Nam quis leo eu enim porttitor mattis vitae vel libero. 
        Curabitur feugiat nec nulla quis luctus.
   </p>
</div>

<button class="btn my-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-  target="#collapse5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="this.classList.toggle('open2')">
                &nbsp;
</button>
```

Essentially the button opens the collapsible DIV, but is it possible to say if id 5 is open, close the other 4?

Or should I just convert these elements into an accordian?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, Just **remove the huge space in `data-  target="#collapse5"`** & it should work fine for you, Let me know otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If you dont want to use accordian then you must place onclick event on other buttons or you can use accordian
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq400doj/) for bootstrap accordian